# Wine Cooler PCB Fuse Blown

Tags: circuit-breaker, appliances, soldering, circuit

I unplugged our wine cooler while cleaning. When I plugged it back in, I instantly heard a "pop" sound and noticed a burning smell. I immediately unplugged it, then opened up the back. Upon inspection, I found an obvious blown fuse (burnt glass fuse) attached to the circuit board. The electrical and mechanical sections were heavily covered in dust.

I can solder on a new one, but I am having a hard time finding a replacement fuse. Here are the specs:

Make: Frigidaire
Model: FWC084HM
Serial #: YR44800497
Rated Current: 0.8A
Rated Voltage: AC 110v
Rated Frequency: 60Hz
Power Input: 50W
Volume: 23L
Circuit Board: PCB121110K1
Fuse: 2.5A / 250v

Questions:
1. Where do I find a replacement fuse for this? I have searched numerous sites and called Frigidaire. No luck.
2. How can I tell if this is a fast-acting or time-delay? The only engravings on the fuse are "5G 2.5A 250v"

Comment: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Littelfuse/0217025MXEP?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsNIlwy3aAdUVxIQvxhy%252BigYReTwQ73yLc%3D

Comment: @AlaskaMan That was fast! Thank you! Can I ask how you found it? I searched this site as well, but must not have inputted the correct search criteria.

Comment: I think the keywords in your question were "glass fuse" and "soldered".  So that reduced it down to a common electronic equipment fuse with leads.  Frigidaire doesn't sell fuses but Mouser, Digi-Key, and similar electronic parts dealers do.  The important specs are 2.5A and 250V.  Be sure to match that and order some spares!

Comment: I tried searching for the model # and that was a black hole. I just searched for the fuse with out the 5g ,  2.5A and 250V

Comment: What are the dimensions of the fuse ?  Gma fuses are shorter and smaller in diameter than the old standard automotive fuses and are used on pc boards quite often. If there is a single strand it is fast acting if it looks like a coil on a piece of fiberglass time delay. Google GMA 2.5 amp and there will be results.

Comment: How long was it unplugged? Wondering why it blew, suspecting that it does not have protective circuitry to prevent trying to start the compressor when it's not been off long enough (so a short-term unplugging would be bad, where a longer one would be fine) - this might then also be a problem during a short-term power outage. But if you had it unplugged for 5 minutes or more, that's probably barking up the wrong tree...